# start application (from jar) on Weblogic startup

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c

I'm using Weblogic 12c, I need to run app before/with the web app starts.
the app should fetch information and write it to db.
I read that in previous versions of WL programmers used to work with ApplicationLifecycleListener, but it is deprecated now.

I'm compiling the project to ear file.
I also tried to use ejb3.2 eager singleton, but it didn't worked.

Is there any working alternative?

Comment: Have you looked into changing deployment order? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24443/managing.htm#DEPGD305 Do you have two apps and one needs to wait for the other?

Comment: [update] I solved this by using EJB3.1 eager Singleton, I'm calling the functions I need using the @PostConstruct annotation

Comment: if you want, you can write what you did to fix it as an answer and mark it accepted. It may help other people in the future

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by creating EJB as the following:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class StartupBean {

@PostConstruct
private void startup() { ... }

@PreDestroy
private void shutdown() { ... }
...
}
```

Creating the EJB Singleton instances is one of the Weblogic life cycle init calls, I put my java code under startup()  method.